Why is "input()" raising "unexpected EOF while parsing" error?
I'm coding in Python. I wrote this code in text editor:
input ()

Then saved as spam.py. In the terminal, it was successfully running by typing:
$ python3 spam.py

But when I ran the same code in interactive session by typing:
import spam

Then I was facing runtime error which was "unexpected EOF while parsing". How can I solve this error?

Please show the code, we cannot guess what you have written.

It sounds like you're accidentally running Python 2 in the interactive session. I think there's an existing question about this, lemme see if I can find it...

Can you please update your question with the following, so other can get a better idea about the issue : your code, output and the python version that is installed in your machine?

@OldBoy They did post the code, it just wasn't formatted properly.

@Sandun The code is already included. The output is too, but maybe you mean you want the full error message with traceback?

I found a bunch of related questions, but either they were people using Python 2 and misunderstanding how it works, or they were closed.

@wjandrea I can only see this as the code " input () ". And yes, a copy paste output with the error would be more helpful to understand.

@Sandun input() is all the code. That's all you need to reproduce the error in Python 2. I just posted an answer.

Related: input() error - NameError: name '...' is not defined

@wjandrea Well you must have X-ray eyes. All I can see is a single input() statement with no other detail.

You're accidentally running Python 2.
In Python 2, input() did the equivalent of eval(input()) in Python 3, and eval() expects a non-null string, so that it can evaluate it. For more details, see screenglow's answer here.
To illustrate
I'll run input() and enter nothing.
Python 2:
>>> input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Python 3:
>>> input()
''
>>> eval(input())  # or `eval('')`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

